# Generated WYSIWYG gallery with individual gallery_page templates

Tags: gallery

I am in the process of making my first theme, and have created the basic pages index.php, front_page.php, single.php and page.php, I also wanted to add a gallery template page.
The idea being the gallery page will differ slightly in format as in no sidebar etc, and I would also like to add further gallery pages after that which will exploit different lightbox and image effects.  I can see how to style the individual images using Firebug on an existing gallery so that seems fairly basic.

What I can see so far is creating a gallery via the WYSIWYG editor in Wordpress on a default page, appears to revert to page.php.  I created a gallery.php and selected this in the dropdown box under page attributes, but the gallery failed to appear using this method.

Can someone give me the heads up as to what happens when a gallery is created via the WYSIWYG editor, or is there a link that gives a good rundown of the process that is happening?

This may not be possible and I suspect the core Wordpress needs some tweaking to achieve what I have in mind, and I have no intention of tweaking as I am just a beginner!  I would also sooner avoid a plugin at this stage like Nextgen gallery.

Or is there a different better method you can suggest?

Thanks,

Ant

Answer (score 0):

Create a [page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates) for gallery in your desired format. Then choose the created template while you add contents for the gallery page.

[image: Choosing gallery page template]

You can use [shortcodes](http://codex.wordpress.org/Gallery_Shortcode) for customizing your gallery.

Comment: Hi Lakshmanan,  I tried this and it failed to show the images on the gallery_template I had created, despite me selecting it from the drop down list as per your post.  I have found an interesting post though on another site which I am attempting to emulate http://ottopress.com/2011/photo-gallery-primer/